# Crypto module and Encryption method not working

Tags: python, django, encryption, aes

Basically, my question is divided into two problems, first of all, I am having this problem when I try running this code [code below] and get an error, like this:

```py
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3d0c04910b61> in <module>
      1 import hashlib
----> 2 from crypto import Random
      3 from crypto.Cipher import AES
      4 from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name 'Random' from 'crypto' (C:\Users\Ahmad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\crypto\__init__.py)
```

The second problem is when I enter text, i.e: "**My data is here**" I got the encrypted text as : "***GIdd+zxj8m0nMeh7wmZJ+Q==***" but reversing the process in decryption it outputs a different text, to validate the process I am using and checking through https://aesencryption.net/ as reference in my work.
**My Code:**

```py
import hashlib
from crypto import Random
from crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode


class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.block_size = AES.block_size
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()

    def encryption(self, plain_text):
        plain_text = self.__pad(plain_text)
        iv = Random.new().read(self.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt(plain_text.encode())
        return b64encode(iv + encrypted_text).decode("utf-8")

    def decryption(self, encrypted_text):
        encrypted_text = b64decode(encrypted_text)
        iv = encrypted_text[:self.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        plain_text = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_text[self.block_size:]).decode("utf-8")
        return self.__unpad(plain_text)

    def __pad(self, plain_text):
        number_of_bytes_to_pad = self.block_size - len(plain_text) % self.block_size
        ascii_string = chr(number_of_bytes_to_pad)
        padding_str = number_of_bytes_to_pad ** ascii_string
        padded_plain_text = plain_text + padding_str
        return padded_plain_text

    @staticmethod
    def __unpad(plain_text):
        last_character = plain_text[len(plain_text) - 2:]
        return plain_text[:-ord(last_character)]
```

Comment: I'm unsure if asking these two problems in one question makes sense as they are unrelated. However, can you provide the actual package name (and a link to the pypi listing) of what you are using? For example, [pycrypto](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/) uses `Crypto` rather than `crypto` but it provides the same methods.

Comment: @Kraigolas I installed via *pip install Crypto*

Comment: How do you know that the logic of your application is compatible with that of https://aesencryption.net/? Don't you want to use [_PyCryptodome_](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/) and doesn't [_pip install Crypto_](https://pypi.org/project/crypto/) install a different library?

Comment: if you run `import crypto` and `print( crypto.__file__ )` then you get path to source code. I check it and it doesn't have `Random` and it doesn't have `Cipher import AES` - it can means you installed wrong module. Module doesn't have the same name in `pip install` and in `import`

Comment: @Topaco If you can post it as an answer so I can accept it and upvote it, that is right what you are saying!

Comment: Sure. I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `__pad()` method `**` is to be replaced by `*`:

```py
padding_str = number_of_bytes_to_pad * ascii_string
```

In the `__unpad()` method the padding size is to be determined from the *last* byte:

```py
last_character = plain_text[len(plain_text) - 1:]
```

With these changes the code can be executed successfully with [*PyCryptodome*](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#cbc-mode), see also [here](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/) for the installation.

---

Padding does not need to be implemented explicitly. *PyCryptodome* supports various paddings (including PKCS7) in a dedicated module ([`Crypto.Util.Padding`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html?highlight=padding#crypto-util-padding-module)).

---

Please note that deriving the key from a password with a digest is generally insecure. It is more secure to use a reliable key derivation function such as Argon2 or PBKDF2.